# JavaScript, numbers and strings

Tags: javascript

I need to automatically populate certain cells of a table according to the cell name (that as to be a number) but when you call the cell by it's name it gets interpreted as it's index number and instead of populating the correct cell it will populate the ordinal cell corresponding to the index.

```
document.getElementById("myTR").cells['9'].innerHTML = "testValue"

//the following doesn't work either 
a ='9'  or  a = 9
b = a.toString()
document.getElementById("myTR").cells[b].innerHTML = "testValue"
```

Any ideas how to solve this?
I've tried to aggregate a letter to the number (9n) and it works, I just wonder if there is any know procedure for this.

Comment: It's [working here](http://jsbin.com/arunuw/2/edit).

Comment: Yes but I really need to call it by name not index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr id="myTR">
        <td>Row1</td><td name="9">Row1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Row2</td><td>Row2</td></tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
var x='9';
document.getElementsByName(x)[0].innerHTML = "testValue";
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/arunuw/5/edit).

### Also try to avoid to declare names that begins with numbers.

Comment: don't need to declare it before, "document.getElementsByName('9')[0].innerHTML = 'testValue'" works fine, thanks!

Comment: Just one question, what does the '[0]' do?

Comment: I guess it is the first element found with the provided name right?

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementsByName('9')[0].innerHTML = 'testVal';
```

gets elements by name, selects the first (only) element and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: I think that wen you call "getElementById()" the result is an object with the elements inside it, then you cant call a getElementsByName() on it it throws an error "getElementsByName is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I will get frowned upon by JS purists, but I suggest using jQuery for this, this is what it was built for:

```
$("#myTR TD[name='9']").html("testValue");
```

This *should* get the cell named 9 in the `tr` tag with id `myTR`

Heres a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/aZEXV/1/

Comment: That's exactly what he didn't want :)

Comment: jQuery is still JavaScript, usually if they dont want to use jQuery, they state that explicitly. :)

Comment: Well, thanks Jeff but this is exactly the problem, I don't want to get the 9th cell, I want to reach a cell named '9' and I really don't want to use jQuery for something so simple.

Answer (score 1):

try this if the name is unique:

```
document.getElementByName('9').innerHTML = 'testValue';
```

by the way, I suggest u use jquery to operate the cell, follow is the code use jquery:

```
$('td[name=9]','#myTR').html("testValue");
```

Comment: "document.getElementByName('9').innerHTML = 'testValue'"
' doesn't work but "document.getElementById('9').innerHTML = 'testvalue'" works

Comment: the name is unique, but it doesn't work, no error but it's not changing anything

Comment: "document.getElementsByName('9')[0].innerHTML = 'testValue'" this works

Comment: Sorry, I forget standard js do not like jquery can detect if it is a list